# need assistance with recursive method in Java

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm kinda new to programming and need help doing a recursive method.I have a method that picks a random space in a 2d array and then I want to check if the space is free.If the space is free I want to use that space but if it isn't I want to pick a new random space in the 2d array.Thanks

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
public class WordSearchPuzzle
{
    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords ;
    private int letterCount = 0 ;
    private int gridDimensions;

    public WordSearchPuzzle(ArrayList<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }

    private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        int i, itemLength;
        String item;
        for (i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(); i++) {
            item = puzzleWords.get(i);
            itemLength = item.length();
            letterCount = letterCount + itemLength;
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 2;
        puzzle = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions] ;
    }

    private void generateWordSearchPuzzle()
    {

    }


    public void firstSpace(String Word) 
        {  
            int row, column;
            row = (int)(Math.random() * gridDimensions +1);
            column = (int)(Math.random() * gridDimensions +1);
            if(puzzle[row][column] != ' '){
                firstSpace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: This doesn't sound a problem where recursiveness is a good, or even nearly-decent, solution. Just make a while-loop picking a random space and check if it is free.

Comment: What is the problem and what is your exit condition? Did you define your boundaries?

Comment: I keep getting this error when compiling: method firstSpace in class WordSearchPuzzle cannot be applied to given types; required:java.lang.String    found:no arguments  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: thanks mads for the suggestion I already have the loop to check if the rest of the spaces are free in my placeWord method

Comment: You pass a string into the firstSpace(String) method and you are seeking a 2D index in a char array. What exactly do you want to do with the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding 1 in your index calculations is necessary and could perhaps cause an array out of bounds exception. Although, that depends on your definition of gridDimensions.

The problem you specified in the comments is because the Java compiler was trying to find a method named 'void firstSpace()', this is a different method that 'void firstSpace(String word)'.

```
public void firstSpace(String word) 
{  
    int row, column;

    // No need to add 1, Java arrays are accessed with the first index 
    // being 0. Math.random() returns from 0 up to but not including 1.0.
    // e.g. array size = 50, min index = 0, max index = 49
    // Lets say you get very close to 1 e.g. 0.9999, then 
    // 0.9999 * 50 = 49.995 (after integer truncating you have 49)
    row = (int)(Math.random() * gridDimensions);
    column = (int)(Math.random() * gridDimensions);

    if(puzzle[row][column] != ' ') { 
        // If this element is not "empty" then run the method again 
        // using recursion. null might be a better choice to compare
        // to depending on how you initialized the array.
        firstSpace(word);
    } else {
        // Otherwise we're finished and we can set the array element
        // to the new word.

        // (Assumed post condition (you might want to do something else once you
        // find a blank index))
        puzzle[row][column] = word;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Simon for the help I'l edit the code to show the full code so far

Comment: Alright, no need to add +1 into your row & column calculation. I have edited the code and explained why in the comments, hopefully it's understandable. 

The new code you have posted is a lot different to what I expected. I thought it was a 'n x n' string array, you have a 'n x n' char array which is essentially a 'n x 1' string array.

Comment: Thanks a million for the help just one last question will I be prompted to enter in a new word when the space is not clear in the recursion part and I'm kinda unsure why you put this part of the code in the else part  puzzle[row][column] = word; because they are incompatible types

Comment: No. The 'else' is for if the program finds a random spot. If it does find an empty random spot then it will be set to the word you passed into the function (assumed that something useful would happen). If **you** (not the computer) want to choose a new _random_ space to set the word then you would not use recursion at all, you would simply return true or false to tell the caller of the method that the space was occupied. The caller of the method can then do something with that result.

Answer (score 2):

The specific issue you mentioned in the comments is because the firstSpace method needs to have a string as a parameter. You should use:

```
firstSpace(word);
```

Also be aware that this method doesn't currently return anything so you have no way of knowing which space it chose.

Comment: Thanks Jim I just have two questions 1) will that prompt me to enter a new word every time it goes into the recursive function and 2)could I do an }else{ return row && column;??

Comment: @user1323808 No, it will just use the same word that was passed in to the first recursive function call. To return two items you'd have to create an object containing them but you are right you can just return these in an else (you would also want to use return firstSpace(word); in the first part of the if though).